# Drag View causes crash because of layout change transition

Tags: java, android

So I have an activity where users can re-order the views (which are created programmatically), this works but often times the activity will crash because of the error: `the specified child already has a parent. you must call removeview() on the child's parent first` I have found this happens because I have layout transitions and I guess the view does not remove until the transition occurs. Anyone have a fix?

Here is the onTouchListener of the view:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                if (Math.round(event.getX()) >= 720) {
                                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                                    v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is the onDrag listener of the view:

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                                return true;
                            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                                LinearLayout owner = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
                                owner.removeView(view);
                                owner.addView(view, getNewViewPosition(fillView.indexOfChild(v), Math.round(v.getY()), Math.round(event.getY())));
                                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```